# Chaining AngularJS Promises in controller. Is this workaround valid?

Tags: angularjs, controller, promise, chaining

Note: this is in TypeScript / Angular 1.4.x

Plunker in javascript: http://plnkr.co/edit/LCka4CFLcRe0lPEF9AM2?p=preview

I have to chain multiple calls with promises. `init3` depends on `init2` depends on `init1`.

Some of the promises need to continue even if they fail. So I had to use the flattened technique here : http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/ To reuse callback code.

The problem is when chaining promises, I completely lose the controller's `this` instance inside 1st chain then (`init2` and `init3`)
So i modified the internal return to pass the controller in the chain so the bindings (bind to controller) and services are accessible.

Is this Valid/Correct? (passing the controller in the chain and reusing the same callback for success/error)

Comments in code also explain/ask questions.

Code:

```
export class ControllerX {

    private myInformation: string;
    private myMoreInformation: string;

    public constructor(private $q: ng.IQService, private service1: Service1) {

        this.init()
            .then(this.init2) //If init() fails dont continue the chain
            .then(this.init3, this.init3); //Even if init2() fail, we continue.
            //init2() cannot fail now but its a recovery example.
    }

    private init(): ng.IPromise<ControllerX> {
        return this.service1.getMyInformation().then((information: string): ControllerX => {
            this.myInformation = information;
            return this; //Push this for the next then
        }); //Do nothing on error, let it propagate.
    }

    private init2(ctrl?: ControllerX): ng.IPromise<ControllerX> {

        if (!ctrl) { //Are we called from a chain
            ctrl = this;
        }

        return ctrl.service1.getMyMoreInfo().then((information: string): ControllerX => {
            ctrl.myMoreInformation = information;
            return ctrl;
        }, (error: any): ControleurListeCours => {
            ctrl.myMoreInformation = DEFAULT;
            return ctrl;
        });
    }

    private init3(ctrl?: ControllerX): ng.IPromise<ControllerX> {
        //blablabla
    }
}
```

Comment: My case is different. The 1st call init() is actually a fat arrow equivalent. The this is working perfectly there. I loose "this" in the 2nd then. (The chained one, init2 and init3) Thats why i have to start returning the controller in the chained promises as parameters.

Comment: i return "this" so init2 can receive the controller as a parameter. (promise chain) i did not find any other way to access the controller inside init2.

Answer (score 0):

> This code won't work as expected.

```
 this.init()
        .then(this.init2) //If init() fails dont continue the chain
        .then(this.init3, this.init3); //Even if init2() fail, we continue.
        //init2() cannot fail now but its a recovery example.
```

If `init` fails, the code will skip `init2` but will be caught by the second `then` method, and `init3` will be executed.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myVm as vm">
  <pre>
init1 status = {{vm.init1Status}}
init2 status = {{vm.init2Status}}
init3 status = {{vm.init3Status}}
  </pre>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myVm', function ($q) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.init1Status = "not done";
    vm.init2Status = "not done";
    vm.init3Status = "not done";

    function init1() {
      vm.init1Status = "init1 failed";
      return $q.reject("init1 failed");
    };

    function init2() {
      vm.init2Status = "init2 done";
    };

    function init3() {
      vm.init3Status = "init3 done";
    };

    init1().then(init2).then(init3,init3);
});
```

**The result**

```
init1 status = init1 failed
init2 status = not done
init3 status = init3 done
```

The [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zsf4j0Lh/)

Comment: @georgeawd Hi, thanks for the answer. I have done some tests and saw that problem. So i modified my case so when i want to stop the chain i return a reject. now it look more like this but the original idea is still valid and working: `init1().then(init2, stop).then(init3,stop).then(stop); function stop(ctrl) { ctrl.loading=false; $q.reject(); }`

Comment: @georgeawd I also see that in pure JS, you do not have the problem i have in TypeScript. My version on plunker is the JavaScript generated from TypeScript compilation. If you debug, you will see that inside init2, the context is lost. Modified Fiddle to manage chain better. : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mmp7923s/7/)

Comment: Sometime Plnkr is down, so this is the TypeScript compiled version in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmp7923s/13/). Console show the `this` problem.